# CDI Conversation instance is not being created

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, cdi

I am try to develop a web application where I need the Conversation scope to carry on with the same String value in multiple xhtml pages with Primefaces 3.5.

When I begin the conversation with conversation.begin(), it throws null pointer exception with conversation being as null.

I know I can't create a instance of Conversation using 'new'. But I can't figure out where am I going wrong and why is it coming to be null.

Please guide.

Snippet of the xhtml where the bean method is called:

```
                    <p:column style="text-align: left" headerText="Deal ID"
                                width="30">
                                <p:commandLink value="#{selectedDealBean.getDealID()}"
                                    action="#{SearchBean.action(selectedDealBean.getDealID())}"
                                     process="@this" >
                                </p:commandLink>
                    </p:column>
```

Snippet of bean:

```
@Named()
@ManagedBean
@ConversationScoped
public class SearchBean implements Serializable {

@Inject
private Conversation conversation;

private DealBean selectedDealBean;
private String selectedID;

private SearchObject searchObj = new SearchObject();  

public void start() {
        this.conversation.begin();
}

public void end() {
        conversation.end();
}

public void submit() {
    System.out.println(selectedDealBean);
}

public String action(String selectedID) {
    String actionstatus = null;

    setSelectedID(selectedID);
    actionstatus = "/common/dealDisplay.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" ;

    start();

    return actionstatus;
}

public String onFinish() {
    end();

    return "/common/create.xhtml";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing annotations. Since you're using CDI you should remove @ManagedBean annotation which is possibly the reason why your injection isn't working.

Comment: I added the @ManagedBean annotation much later into the problem. I am facing the issue even without that. Do I need to add something in configuration or xml?